# xe:listView prevent multiselect

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

If you select multiple entries by using the CTRL button you can select multiple view entries. I need to find a way to prevent this to happen. How can I turn off this feature?

Comment: Haven't found a solution, but it appears to be supported in some way: the xe:listView control is a custom dijit widget and I noticed two related properties in the JS files: singleSelect and bAllowMultipleSelection. Changing this didn't do anything...

Comment: Thanks Mark, I just found listview.js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the listview is a custom dijit control, the properties are adjustable in CSJS.

This is the solution:

```
dijit.byId('#{id:listView1}').bAllowMultipleSelection = false;
dijit.byId('#{id:listView1}').initVirtualList();
```